Initialize the global matrix to a single process, and then distribute to the process grid to use ScaLAPACK rouines
I am working on a problem, and I need to use ScaLAPACK library to optimize the computations. I have to deal with large numerical  problems, where  the number of states nst>20000, therefore the matrices for which I need to calculate the eigenstates are  very large,  and I  do not have a lot of RAM memory.
I realized that the majority of memory space is being used by the global matrix, and when I run the code with Intel OneAPI compiler, the initial matrix is being initialized (PXQ) times, thus leading to memory full capacity and crushing.
The code looks like below:
lworkk =  max( 1 + 6*nst + 2*np*nq, 3*nst + max( block*( np+1 ), 3*block)) + 2*nst
allocate(mat(nst,nst),Z(lld,lld), Aloc(lld,lld),workk(lworkk), wrk(np),Zglobal(nst,nst))      

  Hmatc = dcmplx(0.d0,0.d0)
  do i=1,nst
    mat(i,i)=mat(i,i)+rpsi(i)**2/3.0
    do j = 1,nst
       mat(i,j) = mat(i,j) + rpsi(i)**3/2.0
    end do ! j
  end do ! i

  ! Only the root process needs to send the data
do local_i = 1,np
  do local_j = 1, nq
      ! Determine the process grid coordinates (myrow, mycol) that hold this element!
      i = indxl2g(local_i,block,myrow,0,nprow)
      j = indxl2g(local_j,block,mycol,0,npcol)
      Aloc(local_i,local_j) = real(mat(i,j))
  end do
end do
call pdsyev("v","u",nst,Aloc,1,1,descAloc,W,Z,1,1,descz,workk,lworkk,info)
write(0,*) "info pdsyev", info 
if (myrow == 0 .and. mycol == 0) then 
write(0,*) "eigenvalues in parallel"
!if(myrank == 0) then
! do i = 1, nst
write(0,"(f5.2)") W(1), W(2),W(3),W(nst-2), W(nst-1), W(nst) 
! end do 
!end if 
deallocate(mat,Z,Aloc,workk,wrk,Zglobal)

I tried to initialize only in the process (myrow == 0 .and. mycol == 0) but it gives incorrect results.

you need to distribute the mat matrix since there is not enough memory for it to fit on a single rank.

Thank you Gilles. Exactly as you said, I populated the local matrix directly.
